# :before and :after box shadow not showing up

Tags: z-index, shadow

This is my first posting so I apologize in advance if I am doing anything incorrectly.

I want to have a page-curl box shadow effect on my image slider, as in the "Effect 2" example here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/different-css3-box-shadows-effects

My problem is that the .flexslider:before, .flexslider:after effects are not showing up. I am guessing that it's a z-index issue but I've tried different z-index values and looked through all similar posts I could find on here, and still they wouldn't show up.

If I put a box shadow on .flexslider itself, it shows up.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on this.

Here's my HTML:

```
<section id="home" class="main_section_home">
    <div class="flexslider clearfix">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li><img src='http://eventrenderings.com/TEMP/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/01.jpg' alt=''><p class='flex-caption'></p></li><li><img src='http://eventrenderings.com/TEMP/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/02.jpg' alt=''><p class='flex-caption'></p></li>
            <li><img src='http://eventrenderings.com/TEMP/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/03.jpg' alt=''><p class='flex-caption'></p></li><li><img src='http://eventrenderings.com/TEMP/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/04.jpg' alt=''><p class='flex-caption'></p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>          
</section>
```

My CSS:

```
.main_section_home {
    position: relative; 
}

.flexslider {
    background: #eee;
    width: 94% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    border-top: 12px solid #eee;
    border-right: 12px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #eee;
    border-left: 12px solid #eee;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.flexslider:before, .flexslider:after
{
  position: relative;
  content: " ";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
  border: solid 1px #ff0000;
}

.flexslider:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

Comment: Give the pseudo-elements `position:absolute;` instead of `position:relative;`